# can you use Swift ARC for prompt deallocation of scarce resources (file descriptors, network sockets)?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, automatic-ref-counting, raii

Suppose you are writing a server that receives a lot of socket connections, and you want to make sure you promptly close the sockets as soon as they are no longer needed or in case of exceptions.

Can you piggyback on Swift's ARC to achieve this by wrapping the resource in an object and deallocating it in the deinitialize() method, effectively achieving prompt scarce resource deallocation?

Can the "defer" keyword be used for the same purpose and is 1 method preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Knowing that Swift uses the same ARC implementation as Objective-C, the answer is that it is not recommended to rely on the ARC to deallocate scarce resources.

Apple recommends against using ARC this way here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW13

the stated reasons are (copied from the docs):

- **Order dependencies on object graph tear-down.**
  The object graph tear-down mechanism is inherently non-ordered. Although you might typically expect—and get—a particular order, you are introducing fragility. If an object is unexpectedly autoreleased rather than released for example, the tear-down order may change, which may lead to unexpected results.
- **Non-reclamation of scarce resources.**
  Memory leaks are bugs that should be fixed, but they are generally not immediately fatal. If scarce resources are not released when you expect them to be released, however, you may run into more serious problems. If your application runs out of file descriptors, for example, the user may not be able to save data.
- **Cleanup logic being executed on the wrong thread.**
  If an object is autoreleased at an unexpected time, it will be deallocated on whatever thread’s autorelease pool block it happens to be in. This can easily be fatal for resources that should only be touched from one thread.

On the other hand, the "defer" keyword says the the instructions written under the defer clause will be executed when stack of the current function is unwinded. This has the effect that C++ RAII has, it gives you the ability to tie the lifetime of a scarce resource to the lifetime of a value on the stack.